# Maximize current window completely to hide background in Macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, window-manager

While working on chrome/firefox/finder, I open several windows. Each window has some leftover blank space on right side. This is a huge problem while panning the page using the blue scroll bar. Often I click outside the scroll bar and inadvertently switch to background window. To overcome this, I have to manually drag the current window as right as possible to remove blank space.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this app [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/BetterTouchTool.zip). It lets me define a keyboard shortcut to maximize a window fully, without leaving black spaces on either sides.

1. Download app and open preferences by clicking its icon (boxed index finger) in the menu bar at the top of your screen.
2. Select 'Keyboard' tab
3. Select 'Global' in Applications on right
4. Finally choose Keyboard shortcut and Predefined Action.

I chose the following keyboard shortcuts, which I found safest and non overlapping:

1. <kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> Maximize Window
2. <kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> Maximize Window Left
3. <kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> Maximize Window Right
4. <kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> Maximize window to bottom half

Answer (score 0):

Hold <kbd>Option</kbd> while clicking Zoom (the green + button).

Comment: not working.. Its similar to pressing green + button alone. Also Tried with Shift, Options, Command and Control keys.

Comment: that's weird. Options + zoom works for me

Comment: @jerrymouse Option-zoom triggers the Zoom command for all windows of an application. The way it works is it essentially toggles between "the smallest it can be while containing everything" and the last-used window size for that window. In revolver's case, the custom setting currently happens to be the whole screen and it would do exactly the same thing as simply clicking it without option.